# Building Qt for Android, unsupported option '-fPIC' for target 'x86_64-w64-windows-gnu'

Tags: android, qt, clang++

I am trying to build Qt for Android, following [these instructions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-building.html#installing-the-android-sdk-and-ndk-on-windows). My build fails with the error: “clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '-fPIC' for target 'x86_64-w64-windows-gnu'” (see `config.log` below).

For what appears to be either the same or a related problem [this post](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-native/issues/936) suggests removing the `-fPIC` flag. I do not know if this is possible for building Qt. (I also don't know how to try it.)

`config.log`

```
Command line: -xplatform android-clang --disable-rpath -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/android-ndk -android-sdk C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk -no-warnings-are-errors -android-arch armeabi-v71 -verbose
executing config test verifyspec
+ cd /d C:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\config.tests\verifyspec && C:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" -early "CONFIG += cross_compile" C:/Qt/5.13.0/Src/qtbase/config.tests/verifyspec
+ cd /d C:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\config.tests\verifyspec && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make clean && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make
> del verifyspec.obj
> Could Not Find C:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\config.tests\verifyspec\verifyspec.obj
> del *~ core *.core
> Could Not Find C:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\config.tests\verifyspec\*~
> C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -gcc-toolchain C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/android-ndk/sysroot -isystem C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/android-ndk/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/android-ndk/sources/android/support/include -isystem C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -O2 -O2 -fPIC  -IC:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\qtbase\config.tests\verifyspec -I. -IC:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\android-clang -o verifyspec.obj C:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\qtbase\config.tests\verifyspec\verifyspec.cpp
> clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '-fPIC' for target 'x86_64-w64-windows-gnu'
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:180: verifyspec.obj] Error 1
```

FWIW, I'm otherwise able to build Android apps, including with NDK, on the system. (Also desktop Qt apps.)

Comment: I don't know how to fix your issue, but note that you can install and use the already build binaries Qt offers.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. For Android applications, Qt doesn't provide binaries; you have to build them yourself.

Comment: No, you don't (unless you want/need to), Qt does provide binaries, you just need to install them.

Comment: Could you provide a link please?

Comment: The normal online/offline installer has the option to install Android binaries (arm v7, v8 and x86)

Comment: https://imgur.com/aQlNElr

Comment: There it is. Thank you! I guess the binaries are only available for the very latest versions. (I had 5.13.0, so it wasn't showing them.)

Comment: In the image i have 5.12, 5.9 also had those. I don't know if there are in all versions but at least the LTS ones have them.

Comment: I just checked, 5.13.1 has the binaries for Android too

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to have come about as the result of an incorrect environment variable.

```
set "ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH=armeabi-v71"
```

Should have been:

```
set "ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH=armeabi-v7a"
```